# Python3 scapy using lambda (where it works in 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, scapy

This is my line of code:

```
ans,unans=srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst="192.168.5.0/24"),timeout=2)
ans.summary(lambda (s,r): r.sprintf("IP: %ARP.psrc%   MAC: %Ether.src%")
```

using python 2.7, it scans and print the hosts using arp ping scan
Using python3, it doesn't work and bring up this error:

```
  File "arp1.py", line 9
    ans.summary(lambda (s,r): r.sprintf("IP: %ARP.psrc%   MAC: %Ether.src%")
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10607293/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe   to be honest, I still do not know how to fix the problem

Comment: changing to lambda s_r: r.sprintf ---- says r is not defined

Comment: Figured something out, all good

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured out this can replace the second line:

```
for snd,rcv in ans:
        print (rcv.sprintf(r"%ARP.psrc% & %Ether.src%"))
```

Since, python3 did "Removal of Tuple Parameter Unpacking"