# Why am I getting an invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am trying to set my **init** and when trying to set (x,y), I am getting an invalid Syntax error on the open parentheses on the coordinates.

I feel like this is going to be an obvious mistake but I've been looking at it too long and could use some fresh eyes...

```
def __init__(self, (x,y), size, color = (255,255,255)):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.width = width
```

Comment: Why are there parens around x, y? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: python 3 does not support sublist parameters.

it should be
def __init__(self,x,y,size,color=(255,255,255)):

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607293/nested-arguments-not-compiling

Comment: Didn't realize tuple parameter unpacking was even a thing (in Python 2 only, not anymore in Python 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since x and y are elements of a tuple (if that's what you're trying to create) you don't need to assign individual element in parameters.

```
def __init__(self, coordinates, size, color = (255,255,255)):
        self.x = coordinates[0]
        self.y = coordinates[1]
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.width = width
```

Comment: Or `self.x, self.y = coordinates`. Which has the advantage of throwing an exception if there are more than 2 values in the list/tuple/whatever.

Answer (score -1):

You have to write `__init__(self, v , size, color = (255,255,255))` and pass every `v`as a list.

```
def __init__(self, v, size, color = (255,255,255)):
        self.x = v[0] #first coordinate of v
        self.y = v[1] #second coordinate of v
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
        self.width = width
```