# fail to use collect RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

Please does anyone knows what is the error in this line of code ?
Spend hours searching but didn't succeed to fix it. 
Thank youu in advance,

```
labels = RDD.map(lambda (a, b): a).collect()
```

**Syntax error**

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607293/nested-arguments-not-compiling

Comment: Please see [mcve], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested arguments not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607293/nested-arguments-not-compiling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using python 3 probably it is about [tuple unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) that is not supported in python 3. Also you can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21892989/what-is-the-good-python3-equivalent-for-auto-tuple-unpacking-in-lambda).

Let's say you have rdd of tuples:

```
RDD = spark.sparkContext.range(0, 1).map(lambda a: (a, a))
```

below code will fail with ***SyntaxError: invalid syntax***

```
RDD.map(lambda (a, b): a).collect()
```

but this will work correctly:

```
RDD.map(lambda a: a[0]).collect()
```

Comment: Ok thank you . Then if i need RDD.map(lambda (a, b): b).collect() i should replace it with RDD.map(lambda a: a[2]).collect()

Comment: My mistake, for first(a) tuple element it should  be a[0] and for second(b) a[1]